# Retrieve variable after crash in python

Tags: python

My algorithm has run for a few hours, and when it was done it had to save the variable to a file. Though when writing to a file it crashed due to a memory exception... though the algorithm worked and the variable had the values I needed. Is there anyway to retrieve that variable at this point ? Btw I'm new to python, I'm fully aware what I'm asking is a bit strange.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scipy import *
feature_filename = '4087_features.pkl'
name = 'training'
minimum_features = 3
feature_output = '4087_features_min' + str(minimum_features) + '_' + name + '.txt'

print feature_output

# load necessary files for this step

print 'loading features'
import pickle
features = pickle.load(open(feature_filename, 'rb'))
features_new = {}
t = 0
from scipy.sparse import *
for k in features:
    features_new[k] = t
    t += 1
features = features_new
print feature_filename + ' loaded'

filename_in = '../../../Dropbox/Machinaal_leren/project/project/Emotion_Data_twitter/tweets_' + name + '.mat'
print 'loading ' + filename_in + '...'

import scipy.io
from numpy  import *
try:
    data
    tweets
except NameError:
    data = scipy.io.loadmat(filename_in)
    tweets = data['tweets_' + name].squeeze()
print 'tweets_' + name + 'loaded'

execfile('functions.py')

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


t = 0


def create_feature_vector(tweet, ground_truth):
    feature_row = np.array([0] * len(features))
    tweet = clean_tweet(tweet)
    # N-grams
    for N in range(3):
        for j in range(0, len(tweet) - (N - 1)):
            try:
                key = ''
                for m in range(N):
                    key += tweet[j + m] + ' '
                index = features[key]
                feature_row[index] += 1
            except ValueError:
                pass
            except IndexError:
                pass
            except KeyError:
                pass
    count_features = (feature_row != 0).sum(0)
    if(count_features >= minimum_features):
        feature_row = [x / (1.*sum(feature_row)) for x in feature_row]
        return(feature_row, ground_truth)
    else:
        return (9, 9)

emotions = ['emo_joy', 'emo_fear', 'emo_sadness', 'emo_thankfulness', 'emo_anger', 'emo_surprise', 'emo_love']
N_emo = len(emotions)
ground_truth_list = []

for i in range(len(tweets)):
    feature_vector, ground_truth = create_feature_vector(tweets[i][0], emotions.index(tweets[i][1]) + 1)
    print i
    if(i==0):
        feature_vector_matrix =coo_matrix(ground_truth)

    else:
        if((feature_vector != 9) and (ground_truth != 9)):
            ground_truth_list.append(ground_truth)
            feature_vector_matrix = vstack([feature_vector_matrix,coo_matrix(feature_vector)])




print 'Calculated the matrix, ground truth and saving files'


ground_truth_array = np.array(ground_truth_list)

output = open('ground_truth.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(ground_truth_array, output)
output.close()

output2 = open('feature_matrix.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(feature_vector_matrix, output2)
output2.close()
```

It crashed after this line

print 'Calculated the matrix, ground truth and saving files'

the output

```
Calculated the matrix, ground truth and saving files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Olivier.Janssens\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\MachineLearningBNB\generate_feature_vectors.py", line 99, in <module>
    pickle.dump(feature_vector_matrix, output2)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 615, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 581, in save_tuple
    self.memoize(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python2.7\lib\pickle.py", line 247, in memoize
    self.memo[id(obj)] = memo_len, obj
MemoryError
```

line 99 is :

```
pickle.dump(feature_vector_matrix, output2)
```

I have the ground_truth.pkl and it does seem complete

Comment: Depends on how your code was done. Show some code, or at least describe it, and we can help.

Comment: You ran out of memory trying to convert from numpy to python. Since you are using an opaque dump format anyway, you can save a conversion step with http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dump.html#numpy-ndarray-dump

Comment: @msw Nops! he runs out of memory when converting from Python list to numpy array so the numpy dump method is not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `except MemoryError`

This way you can receive the value if you get an memory exception.

You should use it like that:

```
try:
   // Your code where you get the error
except MemoryError:
   //save or print your values here
```

But if this crash happens more often you might want to optimize your code. Look for very large processing steps. Sometimes it helps to split the process into smaller steps or store the information first.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, based on your code, you aren't in any nested functions or anything like that. So long as you've kept the Python window opened, you should just be able to get the variables, as you would in the code. In other words, just run this bit of code at the python prompt.

```
ground_truth_array = np.array(ground_truth_list)

output = open('ground_truth.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(ground_truth_array, output)
output.close()

output2 = open('feature_matrix.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(feature_vector_matrix, output2)
output2.close()
```

If you don't have a python prompt still, you are basically out of luck, and will have to re-run the data. Keep this in mind for the future to save off variables or test functionality with smaller subsets to make sure that a crash won't kill you.

Comment: I was working in aptana, is that possible there (if you have any experience with it) ? Based on nothing being in my variable window or expression window, I think chances are slim

Answer (score 0):

You get a crash when the code tries to create a `numpy` array from the `ground_truth_list` (which I suppose is very large). My suggestion is to save the list to disk before creating the array. This way you will always be able to read the value of the list (it doesn't matter if you have a Python prompt or not).

**Update**

If the object that can't be pickled is a matrix (as its name suggest) a possible solution would be to split it in several slices (or just to create the slices instead of the whole matrix) and then pickle every slice to disk. Later, when you need to use that matrix you would have to load the individual slices and join again in order to recover the original matrix. Maybe is not the most efficient solution but I think it should work.

Comment: its 250.000 values, and I added what you suggested

Comment: it appears it is not that since I do have that pickle file, it's the feature_vector_matrix (which is a sparse matrix)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your backtrace. The problem is pickling the `featured_vector_matrix` object.

Comment: Np, I just added it. It seems like it. I'll try to find a better way of saving it then :)

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll see if I can do this

Comment: Splitting the sparse matrices works, be recombining them gives an error. So I don't think I can make this work. The link to the problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772575/not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-while-unpickling-and-conc#comment18935274_13772575)